# Higher order directional derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a function defined from $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ to $\mathbb{R}$; then for vectors x,y and a scalar t we have:

$\frac{d^{m}}{dt^{m}} f(x+ty) = \sum_{|\alpha |=m} \frac{|\alpha |!}{\alpha !}(D^{\alpha}(f(x+ty))y^{\alpha}\:$, where $D^{\alpha}$ = $\frac{\delta ^{m}}{\delta _{x1}^{\alpha 1} .....\delta _{xn}^{\alpha n}}$.

How can I prove this using induction? I have no idea where to start. Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to do the cases $\alpha = (0,\dots,0)$, $\alpha = (1,0,\dots,0)$, $\alpha = (0,1,0,\dots,0)$, ..., $\alpha - (0,\dots,0,1)$?

Comment: Should it be over $\alpha$ or m?@EricTowers

Comment: Start with the base cases, $m = 0$ and $m = 1$, which entails the list I wrote.

Comment: Okay I can do that, now how do I extend it to m+1?

Comment: I'd start by working on how the various $\alpha$s for $m = 2$ depend on the various $\alpha$s for $m = 1$.  This could be a blueprint for how to organize the "giant ball of notation" for the general step.

Comment: okay thank you.